# How can I tell Gradle that `gradle run` should depend on the "build" task?

Tags: gradle

I have a very simple Gradle "application" project (as opposed to a "library" project) project.

If I run `gradle clean && gradle run`, the project is not built correctly and so does not run successfully.

If I run `gradle clean && gradle build && gradle run`, the project runs as expected.

The difference in output is that with `gradle build`, there is a `build/libs/app.jar` file emitted.

I have an application block defined as follows, using the Kotlin dialect:

```
application {
    mainClass.set("myapp")
}
```

I thought declaring a dependency on the build task would fix it, but this produces a Gradle error:

```
application {
  dependsOn("build") // unresolved reference: dependsOn
  mainClass.set("myapp")
}
```

How can I tell Gradle that `gradle run` should depend on the "build" task?

Comment: Few things... First, why not `gradle clean build run`?  You can enumerate tasks.  Second, if you want `run` to always `build`, you COULD add `tasks.run.dependsOn tasks.build`... But, in general, it should already be there if you're using most commonly used plugins?

Comment: ah `gradle build clean run` is a step in the right direction